# MOQ - check a method is called with only specific parameters

Tags: unit-testing, syntax, moq

I have a method that assigns some values to a dictionary, and in my Moq test I want to ensure that it is *only* called with a specific set of parameters (i.e., strings).

I've tried a variety of things - Setup, SetupSet, VerifySet, etc. They all let me ensure that a method is called with the parameters I want, which is fine. But how do I verify that it wasn't called with anything else? None of the above methods will catch this scenario.

I tried to use It.IsInRange to specify which params were ok, but that only accepts ints so for a dictionary lookup is not much use.

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this through a strict mock though not strictly AAA (As there is no Assert part, and Loose mocking is more robust) will catch other variations that you don't want.

Just use `MockBehavior.Strict` on your mock.

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Foo(string arg);
}

public class Bar
{
   public void CallFoo(IFoo f)
   {
      f.Foo("hello");
      f.Foo("bar");  // Moq will throw an exception on this call
   }
}

[Test]
public void ss()
{
    var bar = new Bar();

    var foo = new Mock<IFoo>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    foo.Setup(x => x.Foo("hello"));

    bar.CallFoo(foo.Object); //Will fail here because "bar" was not expected 
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm - may not be AAA but it's a small and quite simple test so I'm ok with it in this case.

Answer (score 11):

`_mockChef.Verify(chef => chef.Bake(It.Is<CakeFlavors>(vetoArgsPredicate), It.IsAny<bool>()), Times.Never());`

You can use Argument Constraints aka `It.Is<T>(predicate)` with a method that evaluates to true for invalid arguments and combine that with a Times.Never().

OR
You could strict mocks as another answer here demonstrates ; but they tend to make your tests brittle. So their use is discouraged unless you absolutely need them.

For more details, See bullet #5 and #9 [here](http://madcoderspeak.blogspot.com/2010/01/meet-frameworks-rhino-mocks-v-moq-v.html)

Comment: This was my first approach, which I couldn't quite get to work...I've only got two valid strings, everything else is invalid - would it just be a case of a !(string.Equals(valid1) || string.Equals(valid2))?

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use a callback storing the parameter in a list or something. Then you can assert at the end that the list looks like you expected. In this manner you can keep the AAA pattern.

Comment: If the test were any more complicated I would do this, but for a simple test with only two valid inputs I'm happy with the Strict behaviour trick.